# codeigniter datatables get data from form

Tags: forms, codeigniter, datatables

Pls help basically I want to filter my datatable using form.

each input has a value that would affect the query with submitted form.

here is my JQUERY.

```
$("#submit").click(function (e) {               

    $('#table').dataTable
    ({  

        "sAjaxSource": "index.php/report/get_report",       
        "sServerMethod": "POST",        
        'fnServerData': function (url, data, callback) {
        // Add new data 
            dataString = $("#myform").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                'url': "index.php/report/get_report",
                'data': dataString,
                'type': 'POST',
                'success': callback,
                'dataType': 'json',
                'cache': true
            });
        },                          
        'bServerSide'    : true,
        "aaSorting": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
        "bPaginate": true,                       
        "bSortClasses": false,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "bInfo": true,          
        "iDisplayLength"    : 3,        
        "bScrollCollapse": true,                                        
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search:"
        },
        "bDestroy": true        
    });     
});
```

and this is my HTML FORM

```
<form name="myform">                                        
    <label>Employee:</label>
    <input type="text" name="employeeid" id="employeeid" title="Type Employee" />
    <label>Training Type: </label>
        <select name="trainingtype" id="trainingtype" >
        <option value="" selected="selected">All</option>
        <option value="1">Externally Facilitated Training</option>
        <option value="3">Internally Facilitated Training</option>
        <option value="2">Webcast/E-Learning</option>
        </select>                                       
    <label>Datestart</label>
    <input type="text" class="field size3" name="datestart" id="datepicker_s" />                    
    <label>Dateend </label>
    <input type="text" class="field size3" name="dateend" id="datepicker_e" />              
    <input type="hidden" id="txtsearchid" name="txtsearchid">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

when I submit my form I get nothing.

Im I doing the right way?

pls help.

**GOT IT**

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                //REQUIRED: Add a Post variable with the object value                   
                aoData.push( 
                    { "name": "txtsearchid", "value": $( "#txtsearchid" ).val() },
                    { "name": "datestart", "value": $( "#datepicker_s" ).val() },
                    { "name": "dateend", "value": $( "#datepicker_e" ).val() },
                    { "name": "trainingtype", "value": $( "#trainingtype" ).val() }

                );

                $.ajax( {
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: "POST",
                        url: sSource,
                        data: aoData ,
                        success: fnCallback
                } );
        },
```

this must be the solution for my problem. I didnt used the serialized instead of push

Comment: http://www.grocerycrud.com/ you might want to take a look at grocery CRUD, built in datatable/flexigrid library for codeigniter, save you the time from having to code longer lines, if you want to use datatables

Comment: thank you I already found-out the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug add ons from Mozilla to check the error

Comment: sorry im not familiar using firebug, but I think i have a problem with my datatables jquery. Im newly to datatables. I only have working knowledge on datatables using the basic usage.

Comment: Fire Bug is an add-ons of Mozilla Firefox that track a jquery error .. Just try to research about it and it will help you a lot...

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ just download this firebug and learn how to use it..,,